# Addressing Long Backpropagation Times in CNN-Based Reinforcement Learning

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am currently testing DQN reinforcement learning code in an environment I created myself.
I use both MLP-based and CNN-based models.

The current simple code structure is as follows:

```py
state = env.reset()
while True:
    action = agent.action(state)
    next_state, reward, done = env.step(action)
    agent.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:
        agent.learn()
    
    if done:
        break
```

Using this code for training, there is no problem with the MLP-based model as the time for backpropagation calculations is not large.
However, the CNN-based model has a problem with taking a very long time for backpropagation calculations.

So, I changed the code to the following:

```py
state = env.reset()
steps = 0
while True:
    action = agent.action(state)
    next_state, reward, done = env.step(action)
    agent.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))
    
    steps += 1
    if done:
        if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:
            for _ in range(200):
                agent.learn()
        break
```

At the end of one episode, I used the arbitrary repeat constant 200 for training. In this case, I was able to see the training proceed somewhat well.

Without using a fixed constant, repeating a small number of times such as `int(steps / batch_size)` did not result in significant performance changes.

Do you have any appropriate solutions for this kind of reinforcement learning training?